# How do I update an array value from the database before passing it to the view in CakePHP?

Tags: php, templates, cakephp, pagination

I basically want to be able to pass a value through a function before sending the results to my view...

```
public function listing() {
    $this->set('posts',  $this->paginate('Post'));
}
```

So I want something in there to say, for example:

```
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $post["Post"]["timestamp"] = $this->timeago($post["Post"]["timestamp"]);
    }
```

And then I want to paginate the results with this field, and set 'posts' as the overall array that I send to the view - having updated the timestamp with the 'timeago' function. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: the [TimeHelper in your view](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::timeAgoInWords) might also be of interest

Comment: Exactly, if anything you should be modifying the timestamp on output in the view - "on demand" prior to echoing it. afterFind() callbacks should (maybe) not be used for this, as the conversion might also apply view scope relevant markup etc.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I need to stop my habits of doings things the hard way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may consider to implement those method in model behavior afterFind().
for more information see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I'm making this the answer as it linked straight to the examples I needed to use - for the framework I specified.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic php. In order to modify an array you need to use the $key as following:

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
    $posts[$key]["Post"]["timestamp"] = $this->timeago($post["Post"]["timestamp"]);
}
```

But what you really want is to modify the timestamp prior to actually outputting it:

```
// in your view ctp
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    ...
    $formattedTimestamp = $this->Time->timeAgoInWords($post["Post"]["timestamp"]);
    echo '<span>' . $formattedTimestamp . '</span>';
    ...
}
```

In my opinion output formatting should not be done in the model layer - and especially not using callbacks. If you don't happen to use the pretty formatted fields, you made your model loop over your records for nothing. That's why I prefer doing it "on demand".

Comment: How do I then refactor this back into a $posts array?

Comment: I just gave you all the information there is to it. As I said, it really is just very basic PHP stuff.

Comment: Shame you weren't so helpful and comprehensive with your initial post really. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, sry for that. I just saw how you abused PHP there as a language ;) So I totally fixated on that instead of seeing the whole picture you are trying to solve there.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: Use references.

```
// Note the "&"
foreach($posts as &$post){
    $post["Post"]["timestamp"] = $this->timeago($post["Post"]["timestamp"]);
}
```

This will actually modify the `$posts` array when accessing each `$post`.